# THREAD_STUCK_IN_DEVICE_DRIVER on running Photoshop or Premiere Pro only when on Battery

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, battery

[**Edit :** [***Click here***](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CYnIPktEDdJwVJJhlz6XykQIS5S4WgRV?usp=sharing) to view the dump files.]

It's been more than a month since I'm facing this issue and till today, I've found no answers that could solve this issue.

**Problem:**
When ever I run Photoshop or Premiere Pro on my Windows 10 PC[Lenovo Idea 330S] on battery, I'm getting Blue-screen error. If I do the same when kept on charging, both the programs run without any issues. And I'm pretty sure that, it's happening because of the AMD driver. Specifications given below.

**P.S:** *On uninstalling the AMD Drivers completely, I'm not at all facing any sort of issues. Which confirms that the Blue Screen error is caused due to AMD Driver which is installed.*

Things I've tried to solve the issue:

- Set both the applications to `maximize performance` in Graphic Settings under display settings.
- Create Custom battery profile and set everything to `maximize performance`.
- Re-install Both the applications.
- Reset entire PC.
- Re-install AMD drivers from scratch.
- Update the drivers.

**My Laptop Specs:**
**Name :** *Lenovo Ideapad 330S-151KB*
**Processor :** *Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz 1.80*
**RAM :** *8.00 GB*
**Graphics Card :** *2GB(AMD Radeon 540 GPU)*
**System type :** *64-Bit OS, x64-based processor*
**Edition :** *Windows 10 Home Single Language*
**Version :** *2004*
**Graphics :**

- *Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620*
- *Radeon(TM) 540 Graphics(Adrenalin 2020 software 20.10.1)*

***Any kind of suggesstions to solve my issue is heartly welcomed!***

Comment: Did you update BIOS and also Firmware suggested by the Lenovo Driver update app?  You may need to wait for a new driver to come along.

Comment: @John, yea, everything's updated. And I just downgraded the AMD software to it's recommended version and I'm still facing the same problem of blue screen error.

Comment: I would report this to Adobe with a summary of the information you have amassed here.

Comment: Switch off hardware acceleration in Pshop & test again. I presume you are on Ps 2020 [I'd always wait for at least the x.1.1 version before going to 2021.]

Comment: @Tetsujin, BS used to occur even in PS 2020, and also in 2021. But only when the laptop not on charging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the **AMD Graphics Driver Software**.

**Solution:**
Download [***DDU(Display Driver Uninstaller)***](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/)
Then,

- Boot PC in **Safe Mode** by pressing **Shift key** when clicking *restart button*.
- Change Startup settings - Press F4 or 4 to Boot into Safe Mode
- Run the [***DDU***](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/)
- Update the GPU driver by clicking on **OPTIONAL UPDATES** that comes under **Updates** in settings.

**Never** update the GPU Driver Software!